# ContentSecuritypolicy in helmetjs

Tags: helmet.js

When I added helmet.js in my code everything went blank, then I made ContentSecurity to false, some of the styles came back but not all, then I uninstalled helmets but nothing was changed, then I copied the whole code in new file ensuring not to use helmet.js but that file also didn't work. What is going on, I can't understand anything.

Comment: Helmet maintainer here. My guess: this is happening because you need to clear your browser's cache. I'm also curious to know what errors you're seeing in your browser's console.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.